# How to use js2xmlparser to output xml

Tags: node.js

Hi currently i am using js2xmlparser module to generate XML using node.

I have managed to structure most of the xml as required but not sure how to iterate through Json object as below and format xml as required:

Here is the sample Json object:

```
Json data format as (data):
{
    Group-type-1:"Value1",
    Group-type-2:"Value2",
    Group-type-3:"Value3",
    Group-type-4:"Value4"
}
```

Expected XML data format:

```
<main-group>
    <group>
        <name>Group type 1</name>
        <value>Some value</value>
    </group>
        <group>
        <name>Group type 2</name>
        <value>Some value</value>
    </group>
        <group>
        <name>Group type 3</name>
        <value>Some value</value>
    </group>
        <group>
        <name>Group type 4</name>
        <value>Some value</value>
    </group>
</main-group>
```

Here is what I have done so far:

```
parsedBody = JSON.parse(data);

"main-group":{
            "group":{
                "name":"Group type 1",
                "vale":parsedBody["Group-type-1"]
            },
            ...
            ...
            ...
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use an array.

The following example uses the latest version of js2xmlparser (2.0.2, at the time of writing):

```js
var js2xmlparser = require("js2xmlparser");
js2xmlparser.parse("main-group", {
    "group": [
        {
            "name": "Group type 1",
            "value": "Some value 1"
        },
        {
            "name": "Group type 2",
            "value": "Some value 2"
        },
        ...
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
var js2xmlparser = require("js2xmlparser");

var data = {
    "@": {
      "type": "individual"
    },
    "firstName": "Prakarsh",
    "lastName": "Kesharwani",
    "dateOfBirth": new Date(1993, 9, 07),
    "address": {
        "@": {
            "type": "home"
        },
        "streetAddress": "3212 22nd St",
        "city": "Gwalior",
        "state": "MP",
        "zip": 474001
    },
    "phone": [
        {
            "@": {
                "type": "home"
            },
            "#": "123-555-4567"
        },
        {
            "@": {
                "type": "work"
            },
            "#": "789-555-4567"
        },
        {
            "@": {
                "type": "cell"
            },
            "#": "456-555-7890"
        }
    ],
    "email": function() {
        return "mudeet2@gmail.com";
    },
    "notes": "Prakarsh profile is not complete."
};

console.log(js2xmlparser("person", data));

 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <person type="individual">
     <firstName>Prakarsh</firstName>
    <lastName>Kesharwani</lastName>
     <dateOfBirth>Mon Sep 07 1993 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)</dateOfBirth>
     <address type="home">
         <streetAddress>3212 22nd St</streetAddress>
         <city>Gwalior</city>
         <state>MP</state>
         <zip>474001</zip>
     </address>
     <phone type="home">123-555-4567</phone>
     <phone type="work">789-555-4567</telephone>
     <phone type="cell">456-555-7890</phone>
     <email>mudeet2@gmail.com</email>
    <notes>Prakarsh profile is not complete.</notes>
</person>

 - List item
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.